# Does the Nth iteration of Bellman-Ford relax every edge reachable from a negative cycle?

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, weighted-graphs, dag

Consider a graph $G$ with $N$ nodes, with the distance of each node initially set to infinity (there is no start node). If there are no negative cycles in the graph, then after $N - 1$ iterations of Bellman-Ford, any additional iterations will not modify the distances (the distances are stable).

On the other hand, if there are negative cycles in the graph, then the $N$th, $N+1$th, ... iterations will continue to decrease the distances of nodes reachable from any negative cycles in the graph.

The question is: will the $N$th (and only the $N$th) iteration relax every edge reachable from a negative cycle? That is, does it suffice to perform $N$ iterations to find all edges reachable from a negative cycle?

Comment: If there is no start node, then there is no node with distance $0$. Then, how the distance will decrease in any iteration? all would stay infinity forever.

Comment: True: I meant to include that assume that the initial distances are set to some arbitrarily large value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a simple counter-example.

Let $V = \{a,b,c,d\}$ be a vertex set with all the initial distances set to arbitrarily value $D$.

There are the following directed edges with weights:

1. $w(a,b) = -3$
2. $w(b,c) = 1$
3. $w(c,a) = 1$
4. $w(b,d) = -3$

Then the edge $(b,d)$ relaxes in the $1$st, $2$nd, and $5$th iteration, and not the $4$th iteration.